# Erro ao publicar relatório Power BI na Workspace

Tags: sql-server, microsoft, powerbi

Boa tarde tenho a seguinte estrutura montada na minha maquina pessoal:

SQL Server **->** Servidor Analysis service **->** Power BI **->** Relatório Power BI publicado na Web.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente no modo direct Query, exceto quando publico o relatório na Web, onde eu recebo o erro =

> Esse relatório não pode acessar a fonte de dados. Entre em contato com
> [Meu usuário], o autor para realizar a correção.

Dados importantes:

- Esse erro só ocorre no modo direct Query, no modo carga funciona perfeitamente, isso mostra que o
  Gateway funciona perfeitamente.
- A base de dados publicada na Web recebe atualizações sem problema.
- Meu usuário criou e tem acesso administrador em todas as etapas do processo.
- Uso a ultima versão do gateway, do Power BI.
- Repare que o erro diz que o relatório não pode acessar a fonte de dados que no caso o conjunto de
  dados. Não fala nada de permissão de acesso.

Em fim, o relatório só não funciona no modo DirectQuery publicado na Web, para mim o relatório web não se comunica com a base de dados que está na Web. Tem 3 meses que faço testes com a própria Microsoft e nem eles sabem o que esta acontecendo.

Alguém já teve a infelicidade de passar por isso, ou tem uma dica, pois ja tentamos de tudo.

Vou por algumas imagens para tentar ilustrar.

[image: Erro recebido no relatório Web]

[image: Conjunto de dados atualizando perfeitamente.]

[image: Gateway funcionando OK]

Answer (score -2):

Após muitos testes e analises junto a equipe da Microsoft encontramos o problema.

Para utilizar o Analisys Service local em conexão com o Power BI é obrigatório o uso do Active Directory como forma de autenticação. Sem um active directory implantado local ou em nuvem não é possível usar o Power BI em conexão com o analysis service.

Isso nem a propria microsoft soube informar de cara, foram precisos varios meses de testes e tentativas, com equipes da microsoft de de outros paises, e no final achei o motivo em um video no youtube.

Espero ter ajudado.